# Email is send but email content is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, email

Email code:

```
public function getNotification() {

    return Mage::getStoreConfig('example/general/notification');
}

public function sendEmail() { 
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $templateId = Mage::helper('example')->getNotification();
        $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($templateId);
        $senderMail = Mage::helper('example')->getEmailAddress();
        $senderName  = Mage::helper('example')->getName();
        $receiver = array(
                $senderMail => $senderName,
                $authorMail => $authorName
            );

        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject("New Notification Added For ". $productName);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($senderMail, $storeId);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($senderName, $storeId);
        $emailTemplate->send(array_keys($receiver),array_values($receiver), $post);
 }
```

my code in config.xml

```
<template>
            <email>
                <general_notification translate="label" module="example">
                    <label>Notifications</label>
                    <file>notification.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </general_notification>

            </email>
        </template>
```

system.xml

```
<notification>
<label>Notification send to admin and customer</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>


    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

</notification>
```

Now In **System > Transaction Email** I m add New template and save that template In config I m get template name but using this template my mail is send but Email is empty. there is no content display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m just change my email method

```
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_CONTRACT_NOTIFICATION = 'example/general/notification';

 public function sendEmail() { 
 $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
          $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
          $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
          $templateConfigPath = self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_CONTRACT_NOTIFICATION;
          $receiverMail= 'abc@example.com';
          $senderMail = Mage::helper('example')->getEmailAddress();
            $senderName  = Mage::helper('example')->getName();

          $sentFrom = array('email'=>$senderMail,'name'=>$senderName);
          $template = Mage::getStoreConfig($templateConfigPath, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
          $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()))
              ->($template,$sentFrom,$receiverMail,'admin',$post);
 }
```

This is work for me hope so this will help other

Answer (score 0):

you can use `load` function for this like below

```
$this->_email_template = 'id of template' // int

 $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($this->_email_template);  

 $vars = array('ReviewURL' => $ReviewUrl,
                            'ProductName' => $productName,
                            'url' => $productUrl,
                            'ProductImage' => $productImage,
                            'couponcode'=>$couponCode);

                        $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($vars);

                        $from = $this->getFromMail($this->_identity);
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($from['email']);

                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($from['name']);
                        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
                        $success_flag = $emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(), $billingAddress->getFirstname(), $vars);
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: not working....

Comment: recheck your template path in config.xml

Comment: which path i cant understand . i write code for email in above. is there any other code write in config.xml?

Comment: are you able to see your template name in admin ?

Comment: In  System > Transaction Email > New Email Template? if yes there is no template name

Comment: so there is some error. your template should be there. :(

Comment: How to solve this?